# Possible to play sounds the same way in desktop app and applet?

Tags: java, applet, javasound, audio-player

In java desktop application I can just load a clip like this:

```
clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(path)));
```

And then play it with `clip.start();`

However in applet I have to use AudioClip, which (as far as I know) is not comparable with this.

Is there any other solution than doing this? :

```
if (applet) {
    // play applet way
} else {
    // play desktop way
}
```

Comment: you could use AudioClip for all the cases and skip the conditional statement.

Answer (score 2):

> However in applet I have to use `AudioClip`..

That's not true.  The Java Sound based `Clip` works just fine in applets.  Use `Clip` for both.